# Primary Key for Users per Module? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I'm making a DB in PostgreSQL and I need a little help.

The user control work with LDAP, and I have a table called `modules` where I put all the information about the system modules,

Then I created a table called `user_module` where I put the username and the integer that references a module (in modules table), in this table, you can add/drop rows and I guess I don't need a primary Key for that or isn't it?

I'm using PgAdmin III and it said "I only can View data in this table, I need create a Primary for editing"

Table Code

```
CREATE TABLE public.adm_mod_usu
(
  cusuario text NOT NULL,
  cmodulo_det integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_adm_mod_usu_cmodulo_det FOREIGN KEY (cmodulo_det)
      REFERENCES public.adm_mod_det (cmodulo_det) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_adm_mod_usu_unique_cpermiso UNIQUE (cusuario, cpermiso)
  USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.adm_mod_usu
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.adm_mod_usu TO public;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.adm_mod_usu TO postgres;
```

Comment: Can you give some more details on this user_module table ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables. [**Formatted test**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) but in general a table without a primary key seems dubious

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done

Comment: You have a unique key in that table, why don't you make that a primary key? (Although it's pretty lame from pgAdmin that it doesn't take unique constraints into account, but the it's pgAdmin...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Like that? ALTER TABLE public.adm_mod_usu
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_adm_mod_usu_unique_cpermiso;
ALTER TABLE public.adm_mod_usu
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_adm_mod_usu PRIMARY KEY (cusuario, cpermiso) USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the help from a_horse_with_no_name:

```
ALTER TABLE public.adm_mod_usu DROP CONSTRAINT fk_adm_mod_usu_unique_cpermiso; 
ALTER TABLE public.adm_mod_usu 
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_adm_mod_usu PRIMARY KEY (cusuario, cpermiso) 
USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index;
```

I change the unique constraint to primary.

Comment: I must say I find the prefix `fk_` pretty confusing for the name of a unique or PrimaryKey constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you think? what diminutive would you use?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm trying to create a prefix to all constraints and specify in the name the function (unique,primary,check,foreign key)

Comment: But in that case I would expect the primary key constraint to have the prefix `pk_` not `fk_`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name umm i can change all names: pk (primary), fk(foreign) un(unique) ch(check) ?